# ViewController Classes Not Switching Properly

Tags: objective-c, xcode, model-view-controller, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I have 2 view controllers and I am simply trying to switch between them.

In the first switch event I do this (i.e. viewController1 is loading viewController2 to display):

//viewController1 object

```
if(!_viewController2)
{
    _viewController2 = [[ViewControllerSubClass alloc] initViewWithReferenceToCurrentView:self];
}
[self presentViewController:_viewController2 animated:NO completion:nil]
```

;

//FYI the init method in ViewControllerSubClass looks like this

```
-(id)initViewWithReferenceToCurrentView:(TakePhotoViewController*)view
{
    self = [self init];
    _previousViewController = view;
    return self;
}
```

This works, the view does load this class. However when I try to switch back to viewController1 inside the viewController2 class it does NOT work, and viewController2 takes up the screen.

//viewController2 object

```
-(void)goBackToViewControllerOne
{
    [self presentViewController:_takePhotoView animated:NO completion:nil];
    [self removeFromParentViewController];
}
```

I can 100% verify the code is called but the view is not switching.

Know what I am missing? Thanks!!

Comment: Do you use a UINavigationController?

Comment: I'm using the ViewController you get when you create a single application view. Its just a ViewController

Comment: The way you are doing it is a bit smelly. Try changing the root view controller of the UIWindow instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, there's no need for you to create a special initializer that you pass a pointer of the current view controller to -- when you present a view controller modally, it has a property, presentingViewController, that will point to the controller that presented it.

Second, when you want to go back to the first controller, you should use dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:, not present the first controller.